# python-docx identify page endings

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to detect page endings using python-docx but I can't figure out how to do it, I searched so solutions but they don't work, like finding  in the saved xml.
btw I'm using linux if this is gonna make any difference..

Comment: I'd suggest Page Break ([docs](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/breaks.html)) may help

Comment: No can do. Word decides that in the running application based on the current printing environment and doesn't write "soft" page-breaks to the file. The only way I know of that could be determined is using the Microsoft API on a running instance of Word.